# Jmeter - How to loop data based on the 'jar' file

Tags: loops, jmeter

I want to create scenario where i want use data from jar file into Jmeter Loop logic.

My jar looks like:

```
public String Australia()
{
    String a = "{"
            + "\"location\": {" 
            + "\"lat\": -33.8669710,"
            + "\"lng\": 151.1958750"
            + "},"
            + "\"accuracy\": 50,"
            + "\"name\": \"Google Shoes!\","
            + "\"phone_number\": \"(02) 9374 4000\","
            + "\"address\": \"48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont, NSW 2009, Australia\","
            + "\"types\": [\"shoe_store\"],"
            + "\"website\": \"http://www.google.com.au/\","
            + "\"language\": \"en-AU\""
            +
            "}";

    return a;
}

public String canada()
{
    String c = "{"
            + "\"location\": {" 
            + "\"lat\": -33.8669710,"
            + "\"lng\": 151.1958750"
            + "},"
            + "\"accuracy\": 50,"
            + "\"name\": \"Google Shoes!\","
            + "\"phone_number\": \"(02) 9374 4000\","
            + "\"address\": \"48 Pirrama Road, Pyrmont, NSW 2009, Canada\","
            + "\"types\": [\"shoe_store\"],"
            + "\"website\": \"http://www.google.com.ca/\","
            + "\"language\": \"en-CA\""
            +
            "}";

    return c;
}
```

1) with above data i want to 'feed' Jmeter call as described on the bellow picture

[image]

2) every time i add new country at the jar file, loop be increased accordingly.

Some thought how this could be done, what should i use as variable and how i can tell the loop to increase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) as a child of the `002_2_send payment` request
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def testData = new com.example.TestData()
   def methods = testData.class.getDeclaredMethods()
   def payload = org.apache.commons.lang.reflect.MethodUtils.invokeExactMethod(testData, methods[vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int].getName())
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',payload,'')
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
   ```
3. Define "Loop Count" in the Loop Controller using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) like:

   ```
   ${__groovy(com.example.TestData.getDeclaredMethods().size(),)}
   ```

   [image]
4. Change `com.example` to your own package name and `TestData` to your class name
5. Once you drop the new version of .jar to JMeter Classpath you will need to restart JMeter to pick up the changes

That's it, each iteration of the Loop Controller the JSR223 PreProcessor will execute the next function in your class and update the request body with the returned data:

[image]

References:

- [Java Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: thanks i really appreciate your help! Do i need to put something into 002_2 send payment 'Body Data'? Or its being populate by the preprocessor

Comment: Leave it blank, this `sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',payload,'')` line does the trick. `sampler` is a shorthand for [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html), see the JavaDoc for functions/properties description and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy/) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands available for JSR223 Test Elements