# use jar file + Dynamic values into the loop counter - Jmeter

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I want use improved version of:
[Jmeter - How to loop data based on the 'jar' file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609835/how-can-i-use-jar-file-into-loop-counter-jmeter/58611473?noredirect=1#comment103533736_58611473)

//jar data

```
public class PabBDetailsIncluded {

public static String ARGENTINA(String sourceAccount)
    {
        String a = 
                "{"
                + "\"money\": {"
                + "\"amount\": 10,"
                + "\"currency\": \"EUR\""
                + "},"
                
                + "\"description\": \"Payment\","
                + "\"sourceAccount\": " + sourceAccount + ","
                
                
                
                + "}"
                + "}";
        
        return a;
        }
```

1. with above data i want to 'feed' Jmeter call

just instead of all values to be static from the jar file, i want to pass 'sourceAccount' during the execution, rather then being hard-coded into the jar file.

2. i tell loop counter to count with: ${__groovy(com.example.TestData.getDeclaredMethods().size(),)}
3. into JSR223 PreProcessor  "Script" area is like:

   ```
    import com.example.PabBDetailsIncluded;
   ```

   def sourceAccount = vars.get("accountNumberLogger");

   def testData = new com.example.PabBDetailsIncluded()
   def methods = testData.class.getDeclaredMethods(sourceAccount)
   def payload = org.apache.commons.lang.reflect.MethodUtils.invokeExactMethod(testData, methods[vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int].getName())
   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',payload,'')
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)

The error i got is:

```
2019-11-13 09:55:00,099 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor1 javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.example.PabBDetailsIncluded.getDeclaredMethods() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [5001000001573300]  at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]  at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]   at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_231]  at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:221) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]   at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:44) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:849) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]  at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:467) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]  at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_231] Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static com.example.PabBDetailsIncluded.getDeclaredMethods() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [5001000001573300]    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1501) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]     at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1487) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaClassSite.call(StaticMetaClassSite.java:53) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]   at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]    at Script26.run(Script26.groovy:13) ~[?:?]  at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]  ... 9 more
```

If i use the data from jar file without dynamic values, everything is ok.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the same as for some reason you're using [static function](https://www.baeldung.com/java-static) which needs to be called a little bit differently.

Moreover now you need to pass the parameter to the function and I fail to see where you're passing this parameter.

Your code needs to be amended to look like:

```
def sourceAccount = vars.get("accountNumberLogger")
def testData = new com.example.PabBDetailsIncluded()
def methods = testData.class.getMethods()
def payload = methods[vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx') as int].invoke(testData, sourceAccount)
```

Demo:

[image]

References:

- [Method.invoke()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-)
- [Java: Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Comment: Would it be to much if i ask you, how can i get here the current used MethodName, ex: Argentina? thanks!