# Jmeter - Fetch values from jar file to be used as separate parameters

Tags: jmeter

Based on the thread: [How can i use jar file into loop counter - Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609835/how-can-i-use-jar-file-into-loop-counter-jmeter), i managed to fetch the whole JSON, and used in the body.

Now i need altered version to use only specific parameter, rather then whole body.

1. my script is like: 
   [image]
2. my call is like
   [image]
3. My jar data is like:

   public String Australia()
       {
           String a = {" 
                   + "\"name\": \"Sydney\","
                   + "\"password\": \"test1\""
                   + "}";

   ```
       return a;
   }

   public String Canada()
   {
       String a = {" 
               + "\"name\": \"Toronto\","
               + "\"password\": \"test2\""
               + "}";

       return a;
   }
   ```

What is the easiest way to fetch specific parameter, and loop logic still to be kept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the strings in the .jar file where your PabBDetailsIncluded class lives are valid [JSON](http://json.org/) you could use [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html) class to fetch desired attributes values like:

For the **name**:

```
${__groovy(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(new com.example.PabBDetailsIncluded().Canada()).name,)}
```

For the **password**:

```
${__groovy(new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(new com.example.PabBDetailsIncluded().Canada()).password,)}
```

Demo:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)